# Querying a chain of list of lists with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, foreach, nested-lists

I am working with an XML standard called SDMX. It's fairly complicated but I'll make it as short as possible. I am receiving an object called `CategoryScheme`. This object can contain a number of `Category`, and each `Category` can contain more `Category`, and so on, the chain can be infinite. Every `Category` has an unique ID.

Usually each `Category` contains a lot of Categories. Together with this object I am receiving an Array, that contains the list of IDs that indicates where a specific `Category` is nested, and then I am receiving the ID of that category.
What I need to do is to create an object that maintains the hierarchy of the `Category` objects, but each `Category` must have **only** one child and that child has to be the one of the tree that leads to the specific `Category`.
So I had an idea, but in order to do this I should *generate* LINQ queries inside a cycle, and I have no clue how to do this. More information of what I wanted to try is commented inside the code

Let's go to the code:

```
public void RemoveCategory(ArtefactIdentity ArtIdentity, string CategoryID, string CategoryTree)
{
    try
    {
        WSModel wsModel = new WSModel();

        // Prepare Art Identity and Array

        ArtIdentity.Version = ArtIdentity.Version.Replace("_", ".");
        var CatTree = JArray.Parse(CategoryTree).Reverse();

        // Get Category Scheme

        ISdmxObjects SdmxObj = wsModel.GetCategoryScheme(ArtIdentity, false, false);

        ICategorySchemeMutableObject CatSchemeObj = SdmxObj.CategorySchemes.FirstOrDefault().MutableInstance;

        foreach (var Cat in CatTree)
        {
            // The cycle should work like this.
            // At every iteration it must delete all the elements except the correct one
            // and on the next iteration it must delete all the elements of the previously selected element
            // At the end, I need to have the CatSchemeObj full of the all chains of categories.

            // Iteration 1...
            //CatSchemeObj.Items.ToList().RemoveAll(x => x.Id != Cat.ToString());

            // Iteration 2...
            //CatSchemeObj.Items.ToList().SingleOrDefault().Items.ToList().RemoveAll(x => x.Id != Cat.ToString());

            // Iteration 3...
            //CatSchemeObj.Items.ToList().SingleOrDefault().Items.ToList().SingleOrDefault().Items.ToList().RemoveAll(x => x.Id != Cat.ToString());

            // Etc...
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Maybe provide a simple example outlining your input and desired output.  Because your requirements to maintain a hierarchy AND only have a single child per instance SOUND contradictory, a single child nesting is ~ a list.

Comment: Try building a recursive function that accepts the current category from the loop and the current categoryscheme object, do the deletion in the recursive method, and pass the leftover object back to the function. Am i missing something, or shouldn't this solve the issue? Edit: Also it looks like the loop over CatTree is pretty senseless, 'cause you are deleting all entries, that do not match the current loop var, so in the next iteration, you only have one path through the tree left (assuming every category only appears once), which you are then also deleting. So it'll result in an empty tree.

Comment: @tolanj the objects are way too big and complex for me to post an example here. And yes that hierarchy with a single child looks strange, but it has a meaning. After this code execution, I will pass the object to a method that converts it in the specific XML format, and that has to have that structure.

Comment: @Dr.Coconut Could you please provide me an example of the recursive method you have in mind? I am fairly new to this (and have never used a recusrive method) and an example would really be useful, that's the way a learn better. Thank you

Comment: I think it is much easier to have a while loop because it is easy to keep the reference. Also it should be more memory efficient, because you do not have to heap up a lot of chunk data to merge at the end. What do you think ?

Comment: Can you send test data (a sample?) both of your key elements : CatTree and CatSchemeObj ? It would be a huge help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you to whoever tried to help but I solved it by myself in a much easier way.

I just sent the full CategoryScheme object to the method that converted it in the XML format, then just one line did the trick:

```
XmlDocument.Descendants("Category").Where(x => !CatList.Contains(x.Attribute("id").Value)).RemoveIfExists();
```

Answer (score 1):

So, as i already said in my comment, building a recursive function should fix the issue. If you're new to it, you can find some basic information about recursion in C# [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z3dk2cc3%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

The method could look something like this:

```
private void DeleteRecursively(int currentRecursionLevel, string[] catTree, ICategorySchemeMutableObject catSchemeObj) 
{
    catSchemeObj.Items.ToList().RemoveAll(x => x.Id != catTree[currentRecursionLevel].ToString());
    var leftoverObject = catSchemeObj.Items.ToList().SingleOrDefault();
    if(leftoverObject != null) DeleteRecursively(++currentRecursionLevel, catTree, leftoverObject);
}
```

Afterwards you can call this method in your main method, instead of the loop:

```
    DeleteRecursively(0, CatTree, CatSchemeObject);
```

But as i also said, keep in mind, that calling the method in the loop, seems senseless to me, because you already cleared the tree, besides the one leftover path, so calling the method with the same tree, but another category, will result in an empty tree (in CatSchemeObject).

**CAUTION!** Another thing to mention i noticed right now: Calling to list on your Items property and afterwards deleting entries, will **NOT** affect your source object, as ToList is generating a new object. It IS keeping the referenced original objects, but a deletion only affects the list. So you must write back the resulting list to your Items property, or find a way to directly delete in the Items object. (Assuming it's an IEnumerable and not a concrete collection type you should write it back).

Just try it out with this simple example, and you will see that the original list is not modified.

```
IEnumerable<int> test = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4 , 1 };

test.ToList().RemoveAll(a => a != 1);
```

Comment: yea the recursive method inside the loop doesn't work. And plus, I need to remove the categories from the original object, so that I can send to the next methods afterwards

Comment: So what do you mean with "doesn't work"? Is it throwing an error? What's the behaviour you say that's wrong? Please be more specific.

Comment: Regarding your second point: Yeah, that's why i mentioned, you have to write back the modified list to your property "catSchemeObj.Items" or tell us of which type "Items" is, to check if there's a possibility to directly delete on the source object "Items" instead of creating a temporary List with "ToList".

Comment: Im sorry I wasn't clear enough: it doesn't work because the first time the recursive method is called, it receives a `ICategorySchemeMutableObject` object, but then when it's called again, it is passed leftoverObject which is just a category now, and is of type `ICategoryMutableObject`

Comment: Then you have to overload the method to also accept a category instead of only ICategoryMutableObject. The content of the method should'nt change as it looks like both object types are treated equally. As i said, you should've got the idea by now, we can't provide you a perfectly fitting solution because we do not know enough about the rest of your application, especially types of the objects. So please try to put some effort for yourself, making these possible solutions work in your specific scenario.

Comment: Besides that, i updated my solution according to the new insights i gained from the comments under Botond Bertalans solution.

Answer (score 0):

Edited:

So here is another possible way of going after the discussion below.
Not sure what do you really need so just try it out.

```
    int counter = 0;
    var list = CatSchemeObj.Items.ToList();
    //check before you call it or  you will get an error
    if(!list.Equals(default(list)))
    {
        while(true)
        {
            var temp = list.Where(x => CatTree[counter++] == x.Id); // or != ? play with it .
            list = temp.Items.ToList().SingleOrDefault();

            if(list.Equals(default(list))
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

I just translated you problem to 2 solutions, but I am not sure if you won't lose data because of the SingleOrDefault call. It means 'Grab the first item regardless of everything'. I know you said you have only 1 Item that is ok, but still... :)

Let me know in comment if this worked for you or not.

```
//solution 1
// inside of this loop check each child list if empty or not
foreach (var Cat in CatTree)
{
    var list = CatSchemeObj.Items.ToList();
    //check before you call it or  you will get an error
    if(!list.Equals(default(list)))
    {
        while(true)
        {
            list.RemoveAll(x => x.Id != Cat.ToString());
            list = list.ToList().SingleOrDefault();

            if(list.Equals(default(list))
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

//solution 2

foreach (var Cat in CatTree)
{
    var list = CatSchemeObj.Items.ToList();
    //check before you call it or  you will get an error
    if(!list.Equals(default(list)))
    {
        CleanTheCat(cat, list);
    }
}

//use this recursive function outside of loop because it will cat itself
void CleanTheCat(string cat, List<typeof(ICategorySchemeMutableObject.Items) /*Place here whatever type you have*/> CatSchemeObj)
{
    CatSchemeObj.RemoveAll(x => x.Id != cat);

    var catObj = CatSchemeObj.Items.ToList().SingleOrDefault();

    if (!catObj.Equals(default(catObj)){
        CleanTheCat(cat, catObj);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have to double check :)

Comment: As Dr. Coconut pointed out you have to modify the recursive call, but it should be ok if you use the simple while loop. Not tested though. It is  a job for you :)

Comment: I am trying the while approach. But it gives me an error on this line:

if(!list.Equals(default(list)))

"namespace list could not be found"

Comment: A simple copy & paste won't work here. You have to put a little effort in yourself. "list" is correctly written "List" and also expects a type parameter, e.g. "List<int>" or "List<ICategorySchemeMutableObject>" or whatever type your list actually is.

Comment: Ok I did this, and fixed another line, I think this line:

`list = list.ToList().SingleOrDefault();`

should be like this:

`list = list.SingleOrDefault().Items.ToList();`

however, it does cleans the first category, but then it re-enters the while and it keeps searching for the same 'Cat' (ID) as before in the new list of categories, and it doesn't find it

Comment: I mentioned that in my answer, that's because you previously deleted all categories that did not match the first category, so there is no possible way, that the second category can be found in the tree, because you deleted it. I'm assuming you want to delete all categories except ALL categories in the object CatTree, then you have to try a different approach, than the one you posted. You don't have to loop over CatTree then, instead change the lambda in the recursive function to check if the element is inside CatTree, instead of checking if it's equal to the current looped value from CatTree.

Comment: what do you mean it does not find it ? The algorithm you provided meant: Remove each type of category that is in the CatTree on each level of CatSchemeObject.Items. That is what it does.

Comment: Ok I hope I got it. I will post another solution in a moment

Comment: The CatTree elements indicate the nesting order of the categories. But in every category there are many categories. I have to remove, at every level, all the categories that do not corrsponde to the category id specified for that level. So in the end, what will remain is a long chain of nested categories which have no brothers! just grandparent -> parent -> child, and everyone of them is a lonely child

Comment: Doesn't work, the second time it enters the while, I believe it keeps checking for the same ID, and doesn't find it because it entered the first category. I will go to lunch now, after I'll also try Coconut solutions. Really thanks for your help guys, we are going to figure this out soon